# I am trying to read every value into a python dictionary from the CSV. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, dictionary, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use batch_writer() in DynamoDB (Amazon Web Services).

Comment: That code is very confusing. For example, it isn't obvious why you are storing information in a dictionary when you only ever retrieve the `.values` from the dictionary. Your main problem is that the program is looping through each row in the `languages` file, and for each of those rows it is going through each line of the `area` file. It is _not_ loading all values from the file into memory -- it is simply going through each of them one-at-a-time.

Comment: Can you show the Output you would like from those two input files? We could then advise a better way to write the code. Please Edit your question to show the Output you would like. I'd be especially interested to see how you intend to handle countries that have _multiple languages_ since separating them with commas will not make a valid CSV file. In fact, your sample Languages file is not valid CSV because it has a variable number of columns in each row (eg Algeria has more columns).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Not sure how i will separate  the more than one languages.  I guess for now, i can ignore that  part? The desired output is i want the proper Area for each country. In my screenshot, you see that Area isn't looping right in the DynamoDb table. 

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nested incorrectly. Here is some example code that first reads the languages file into a dictionary, then loops through the area file:

```py
languages = {}
table = []

# Load languages, catering for multiple languages
with open('shortlist_languages.csv') as languages_file:
    for line in languages_file:
        fields = line.strip().split(',')
        languages[fields[0]] = ','.join(fields[2:])

# Load countries
with open('shortlist_area.csv') as countries_file:
    for line in countries_file:
        fields = line.strip().split(',')
        table.append(
            {
                'Country Name': fields[1],
                'Languages': languages[fields[0]],
                'ISO3': fields[0],
                'Area': fields[2]
 
            }
        )

print(table)
```

(I was too lazy to use the CSV functions!)

The output is:

```json
[
    {
        "Country Name": "Country Name",
        "Languages": "Languages",
        "ISO3": "ISO3",
        "Area": "Area"
    },
    {
        "Country Name": "Albania",
        "Languages": "Albanian",
        "ISO3": "ALB",
        "Area": "28748"
    },
    {
        "Country Name": "Algeria",
        "Languages": "Arabic,Tamazight",
        "ISO3": "DZA",
        "Area": "2381741"
    },
    {
        "Country Name": "Andorra",
        "Languages": "Catalan",
        "ISO3": "AND",
        "Area": "468"
    },
    {
        "Country Name": "Angola",
        "Languages": "Portuguese",
        "ISO3": "AGO",
        "Area": "1246700"
    }
]
```

Note that Algeria has multiple languages in its output.

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped. I have another CSV called shortlist_capitals.csv and another csv as well I'd like to add.

Assuming I wanted to add that, how would shortlist_capitals.csv values go into the table as well like with Area? 

The shortlist_capitals.csv contains (Country Name, Languages, Capital) as header. I tried to follow from how you did languages but got stuck. If you could show that capitals as an example, i think i would be golden

Comment: Please try it yourself. If you have a problem, you can always post a new Question. The important bit to realise is that if you want to load data into memory, then **process the data one file at a time**. Do not nest the processing of one file inside the processing of another file. You can also debug your program as you go along -- for example, simply `print()` the data rather than inserting it into DynamoDB. Once everything is being printed correctly, then worry about adding it to the database.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. However, I noticed in the DynamoDB table, the words Country, Languages,ISO3, Area, are ALSO added as a row/tuple in the DynamoDb (along with the proper countries).

How can i make sure that those are not included?

Comment: Please create a new Question and somebody should be able to assist. Please include the code that inserts the data into DynamoDB, together with details about what is inserted and what you'd like it to do instead.